# groovy regex tokenize().grep() function not producing expected answer

Tags: regex, git, groovy

I am attempting to extract the Version tags from a git repo using some regex functions from groovy.

```
def command = "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/sh.exe\" --login -i -c \"git ls-remote user@mysever:myproject.git refs/tags/[vV]*?.*?.*?\""
def proc = command.execute()
proc.waitFor()

def str = proc.in.text
def pattern = ~/^refs\/tags\/[vV][0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/
System.out.println("is everything a string? " + str.tokenize().every{ it instanceof String })
System.out.println("String: $str")
System.out.println("split: ${str.split()}") 
System.out.println("contains refs/tags/V0.0.0?: ${str.split()*.trim().contains('refs/tags/V0.0.0')}") 
System.out.println("contains refs/tags/V0.0.1?: ${str.split()*.trim().contains('refs/tags/V0.0.1')}") 
System.out.println("grep: " + ['refs/tags/V0.0.0', 'refs/tags/V0.0.1'].grep(pattern))
System.out.println("split grep: " + str.split().grep(pattern))
System.out.println("split findAll: " + str.split().findAll{ it =~ pattern })
```

And my output is this:

```
String: SHA1asdf refs/tags/V0.0.0
SHA1fdsa refs/tags/V0.0.0^{}
SHA1hgfd refs/tags/V0.0.l
SHA1dfgh refs/tags/V0.0.l^{}

split: [SHA1asdf, refs/tags/V0.0.0, SHA1asdf, refs/tags/V0.0.0^{}, SHA1hgfd, refs/tags/V0.0.l, SHA1dfgh, refs/tags/V0.0.l^{}]
contains refs/tags/V0.0.0?: true
contains refs/tags/V0.0.1?: false
grep: [refs/tags/V0.0.0, refs/tags/V0.0.1]
split grep: [refs/tags/V0.0.0]
split findAll: [refs/tags/V0.0.0]
```

**Why isn't the tokenize().grep() producing the expected answer?**

I am using *`Groovy 2.3.6`*

**UPDATE:** I've added more test results, *see code and output*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why, but your version `V0.0.1` is actually an character `l` and not `1`.

If you just the run the following sample (just changed the `str`), grep will work just fine:

```
def str = """
SHA1asdf refs/tags/V0.0.0
SHA1fdsa refs/tags/V0.0.0^{}
SHA1hgfd refs/tags/V0.0.1
SHA1dfgh refs/tags/V0.0.1^{}
"""

def pattern = ~/^refs\/tags\/[vV][0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/
System.out.println("String: $str")
System.out.println("tokenize: ${str.tokenize()}")
System.out.println("grep: " + ["refs/tags/V0.0.0", "refs/tags/V0.0.1"].grep(pattern))
System.out.println("tokenize grep: " + str.tokenize().grep(pattern))
```

produces

```
grep: [refs/tags/V0.0.0, refs/tags/V0.0.1]
tokenize grep: [refs/tags/V0.0.0, refs/tags/V0.0.1]
```

Comment: Phew, I thought groovy was broken. Turns out I'm just a bad typer :P

Comment: it happens, keep grooving :)